# mvn spring-boot:run vs java -jar

Tags: spring, maven, jsp, spring-boot

I know it may sound silly question but I am unable to understand the difference between `mvn spring-boot:run` and `java -jar` (.jar file generated with mvn install)

I have a spring boot application with jsp pages in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/`. If I use `mvn spring-boot:run` these pages are served. But If I use `java -jar` these pages are not found by application.

The application that I am working on is at https://github.com/ArslanAnjum/angularSpringApi

UPDATE:
It works with spring boot 1.4.2.RELEASE while I intend to use the latest version i.e., 1.5.8.RELEASE.

UPDATE:
Well I solved the problem by putting jsps in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/ and changing packaging type to war and then running this war using java -jar target/myapp.war and its working fine now.

Comment: can you post your spring application config file?

Comment: I have shared github link. you can clone the repo.

Comment: Did you take your configuration from some sample? I don't think JSP in a JAR (so embedded container) will work with Tomcat

Comment: Same problem for freemarker instead of jsp, and your solution (packaging as war) worked for us too, thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Short answer: `spring-boot:run` is a `java -jar` command *on steroïd* running as part of your Maven build, ensuring all required parameters are passed to your app (such as resources). `spring-boot:run` will also ensure that your project is compiled by executing `test-compile` lifecycle goals prior to running your app.

Long answer:

When you run `java -jar`, you launch a new JVM instance with all the parameters you passed to this JVM. For example, using the Spring doc example

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y, \
    transport=dt_socket, address=8000, suspend=
    -jar target/myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

You will launch a brand new JVM with the given parameters. You need to make sure to include everything needed, such as classpath elements, application parameters, JVM options, etc. on the command line.

When you run `mvn spring-boot:run`, you launch a Maven build that will:

- Run the `test-compile` lifecycle goals, by default it will be `resources:resources`, `compiler:compile`, `resources:testResources`, `compiler:testCompile` goals of the Maven Resources and Compiler plugin.
- Launch your application with a bunch of parameters that will depend on the 
  Spring Boot Maven Plugin configuration you defined in your project (your pom.xml, parents and settings, command line, etc.). This includes among other things:

  - A lot of classpath elements: your `target/classes` folder which may contain resources and libraries required by your app, your Maven dependencies, etc.
  - Whether to fork your JVM or not (whether to create a brand new JVM to run your app or re-use the JVM of the Maven build), see `fork` and `agent` parameter of the plugin

As per:

> I have a spring boot application with jsp pages in
>   /src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/. If I use mvn
>   spring-boot:run these pages are served. But If I use java -jar these
>   pages are not found by application.

It's because the `mvn spring:boot` command will make sure your `target/classes` folder is present in the Classpath when your app is running. After compilation, this folder will contain `target/classes/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF` among other things. Your app will then be able to find `META-INF/resources/WEB-INF` and load them when asked. When you ran `java -jar` command, this folder was probably not on the classpath, your app was then not able to find your resources. (these resources were copied from the `src/main/resources` folder during the `resources:resources` goal)

To have a similar result with your `java -jar` command, you must include your resources on the classpath such as `javar -jar myapp.jar -cp $CLASSPATH;/path/to/my/project/target/classes/`

Comment: I understand. But I am unable to make it functional. can specify what to include after $CLASSPATH ? I have tried /classes/resources/META-INF and META-INF/resources.

Comment: Typically it would be `./target/classes` if you are running the command from the root directory of your project to include the target folder. But that's just an example: the important thing is to make sure that all required dependencies and resources are on the classpath. If everything is packaged in your JAR, then you're fine.

Comment: jsps are present in jar. I tried with spring boot 1.4.2 and it is working. May be its a bug with current version of spring boot. ( 1.5.8)

Comment: That's possible! Or a change in the way things are loaded between 1.5.x and 1.4.x.

Comment: I solved it by changing packaging type to war and putting all the jsps in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views. now its runnable via command java -jar target/myapp.war

Comment: Thanks @ArslanAnjum - changing packaging from jar to war works for us too. otherwise we can only run locally on the development machine

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating a jar file using `mvn package` instead of `mvn install` when you are running jar file using `java -jar`? `package` will create a jar/war as per your POM file whereas `install` will install generated jar file to the local repository for other dependencies if present.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: It all depends on the way, the jar is created. [This](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html) page provides the complete information as how the executable jar or war archives are created using Spring Boot.